# Finding nearest element of an array in a particular column of another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to map one numpy array to another one. My frist array has two columns and thousands of rows:

```
arr_1 = [[20,  0.5],
         [30, 0.75],
         [40,  1.0],
         [50, 1.25],
         [60,  1.5],
         [70, 1.75],
         ...]
```

The second array can have a different number of rows and columns:

```
arr_2 = [[1, 0.45],
         [2, 0.57],
         [4, 0.58],
         [1, 1.69],
         [1, 1.51],
         [1, 0.95],
         ...]
```

I want to compare the values of the second column of `arr_2` with the second column of `arr_1` to know which row of `arr_2` is closer to which row of `arr_1`. Then I want to copy the first column of `arr_1` into `arr_2` from the row with the nearest second column.

For example, `0.45` in `arr_2` is closest to `0.5`, i.e. first row in `arr_1`. After finding that, I want to copy the first column of that row (which is `20`) into `arr_2`. The final result would look something like:

```
arr_2_final = [[1, 0.45, 20],
               [2, 0.57, 20],
               [4, 0.58, 20],
               [1, 1.69, 70],
               [1, 1.51, 60],
               [1, 0.95, 40],
               ...]
```

Comment: Are the values in the second column sorted?

Comment: If you use a numpy array, perhaps you should show arrays instead of lists in your example?

Comment: Dear @MadPhysicist, the second column is sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking up lots of items in an array is easiest done when it is sorted. You can delegate most of the work to [`np.searchsorted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html). Since we want to find elements in `arr_1`, it is the only array that needs to be sorted. I suspect that having a sorted `arr_2` will speed things up by reducing the size of the search space for every successive element.

First, find the insertion points where `arr_2` would end up in `arr_1`:

```
indices = np.searchsorted(arr_1[:, 1], arr_2[:, 1])
```

Now all you have to do is check for cases where the prior element is closer than the current one. There are two corner cases: when index is 0, you have to accept it, and when it is `arr_1.size`, you have to take the prior.

```
indices[indices == arr_1.shape[0]] = arr_1.shape[0] - 1
indices[(indices != 0) & (arr_1[indices, 1] - arr_2[:, 1] > arr_2[:, 1] - arr_1[indices - 1, 1])] -= 1
```

Doing it in this order saves you the trouble of messing with temporary arrays. The first line ensures that the index `arr_1[indices, 1]` is always valid. Since index -1 is valid, the second line succeeds as well.

The final result is then

```
np.concatenate((arr_2, arr_1[indices, 0:1]), axis=1)
```

If `arr_1` is not already sorted, you can do the following:

```
arr_1 = arr1[np.argsort(arr_1[:, 1]), :]
```

A quick benchmark shows that on my very moderately powered machine, this approach takes ~300ms for `arr_1.shape = (500000, 2)` and `arr_2.shape = (300000, 2)`.

Comment: Dear @MadPhysicist, your solution was fantastic. But, now I notices that my real data are a little bit complicated. I said that I want to compare just two columns of two array but now I see it is a littile bit different. I have to compare two cordinates and find the closest ones. It is a little bit complicated and I think it is better to open another issue for that.

Comment: Dear @MadPhysicist, I really appreciate your help. I did not knew anything about upvoting. Definitely, I will do it.

Comment: @Ali_d. No worries. Welcome to the site. FYI: https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do it this way:

```
import numpy as np

arr_1= [[20, 0.5], [30, 0.75], [40, 1], [50, 1.25], [60, 1.5], [70, 1.75]]
arr_2= [[1, 0.45], [2, 0.57], [4, 0.58], [1, 1.69], [1, 1.51], [1, 0.95]]

arr_2_np = np.array(arr_2)[:,1]

for row in arr_1:
  idx = np.argmin(np.abs(arr_2_np - row[1]))
  arr_2[idx].append(row[0])

print(arr_2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But when I run it, I saw the following result: [[1, 0.45, 20], [2, 0.57], [4, 0.58, 30], [1, 1.69, 70], [1, 1.51, 50, 60], [1, 0.95, 40]]. As you see, it has not added any value for the second row of arr_2 but added two values to the fifth row.

Comment: @Ali_d Ok, so you only want to add a single value to each row in arr_2? How should this selection be carried out? I think you need to clarify how you want the selection to be performed to be able to get a better answer.

The solution above appends the value of each row in arr_1 to the best matching row in arr_2 regardless if there already are a value appended or not.

Comment: Yes, I want my code to check the difference between the second column of each row of arr_2 with all values of the second column of arr_1, then find the least difference and add the first column of that row to the arr_2.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Given the clarification given by OP that makes the problem somewhat more complex I don't see a solution without looping unless there exists some function that finds the minimum distance between numbers in two lists of different lengths. Would you mind giving a pointer to where one might look for such a solution as ordinary vector algebra isn't compatible with arrays of different lengths?

Comment: @Marcus. There are plenty of numpy functions for working with arrays of different sizes. I'll post an answer shortly

Comment: I've posted an answer that does not use loops. The other problem with your code is that it does a linear search of the entire array at each iteration. This is O(M * N). A proper search should be able to do this in O(M log N) time.